# Finding the domain and range of the a Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

i have this question

> Let $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $B=\{1,4,6,8,9\}$ and $aRb \iff b=a^2$. Find the domain, range of the relation $R$.

My answer is Domain=(1,2,3) Range=(1,4,9).Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is; $Dom(R) = \{ x : \exists y (xRy) \}$ and $Ran(R) = \{ y : \exists x (xRy) \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks